# Outlining an object using a stencil buffer give wrong result

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glfw, stencil-buffer

I'm trying to use the stencil buffer to draw outline border behind a model.

I'm using 2 render passes, first rendering the model and using `GL_ALWAYS` to write `1` to the stencil buffer and then I render a slightly scaled up version of the model that uses `GL_NOTEQUAL` with ref value of `1` so basically to pass only fragments that are outside the original cube thus making the highlight.

I'm getting weird result, the outline is not fully rendered and when I move my camera enough it disappears completely as if the stencil test of the scaled up cube doesn't pass at all.
Here's the gist of the rendering loop (shader3 just outputs a color for the border):

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClearStencil(0);
    renderer.Clear();    
    ...
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCREEN_WIDTH / (float)SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    UniformMat4f projectionUniform("u_Projection");
    projectionUniform.SetValues(projection);

    glm::mat4 view = camera.GetView();
    UniformMat4f viewUniform("u_View");
    viewUniform.SetValues(view);

    modelUniform.SetValues(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)));

    shader1.SetUniform(projectionUniform);
    shader1.SetUniform(viewUniform);
    shader1.SetUniform(modelUniform);

    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
    glStencilMask(0xFF);

    renderer.Draw(model, shader1);

    modelUniform.SetValues(glm::scale(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)), glm::vec3(1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f)));
    shader3.SetUniform(projectionUniform);
    shader3.SetUniform(viewUniform);
    shader3.SetUniform(modelUniform);

    glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
    glStencilMask(0x00);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    renderer.Draw(model, shader3);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

I first tried it with the `nanosuit` model from crysis and it work as I described not showing all the parts and eventually disappearing when moving the camera. I've decided to try a simple geometry to test this out and tried to outline a simple cube and got the same result:
[image]

Comment: What does `renderer.Clear();`? Does it use [`glClear()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClear.xml) _with_ `GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT`?

Comment: Yep clear the color, depth and stencil buffer

Comment: There is a nice tutorial in [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Stencil-testing). You can compare your code concerning subtleties. From my experience with OpenGL, missing small details often have fatal consequences... ;-)

Comment: Thats my resource actually so I'm not sure what went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the call to  `glStencilMask(0x00);` at the end of the main loop. the default value of the stencil mask is `0xff` (for 8 bit, see [`glStencilMask`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glStencilMask.xhtml)). OpenGL is a state engine. A state is kept, till it is changed again (even beyond frames).
[`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) considers the state of the color, depth and stencil mask. If the stencil mask is `0x00`, then the stencil buffer isn't cleared at all.

Set the stencil mask `0xff`, before you clear the stencil buffer to solve the issue:

```cpp
glStencilMask(0xFF);
renderer.Clear();
```

Comment: But isn't `glStencilMask(0xFF);` used only to mask what we're writing to the stencil buffer and not clearing? Why wouldn't it clear when I set `glClearStencil(0);` and call `glClear(...)` ?

Comment: No, `glStencilMask` specifies the bits which are allowed to be written to. If it is 0 then not any bit of the stencil buffer  is allowed to be written and the stencil buffer can't be changed at all, so `glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)` does nothing.